# Magento: Payment portal forwards - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, magento

Scenario: A magento 1.7.0.0 shop with several extensions, customized themes

Problem: Beginning some changes in the checkout module and theme *some* customers are not forwarded to the payment provider (all of them, paypal, sofort.com, wirecard credit card processing).

What makes it hard to debug for us, is, that we just cannot see this effect on our own. The flow from the customers perspective should be (and which is standard in magento):

1. checkout
2. press "buy now" button
3. a page with the message "if you are not forwarded to *providee* press here"
4. visitor gets automatically forwarded
5. makes payment on providers page
6. return

what customers report is, that they get a blank page on 3. - so obviously this page is not built correctly. but we don't get log entries on our side, and on the providers side are no log entries, as they never reach him.

what we did:

- switch to a completely different checkout
- switched off an extension by the same developer as the custom checkout, which deals heavily in ajax/javascript (it's template-masters fire checkout, ajax pro which is usually very high quality and the support is fantastic, but as they don't see what our clients report, they can't really help either)
- eliminated almost all "small" warnings/errors in the logs which we ignored until then

**how could we possibly debug this? is there a way to write out all page content as it is delivered to the visitor for later inspection?**

**could the problem be somewhere else (apache, connectivity, ssl?)**

Answer (score 0):

why not start with regular debugging steps and common sense:

- if it is a blank page then it must be a php error
- my php errors are logged to error_log (see from phpinfo where exactly)
- lets observe all the server logs in var/log and other apache and php related logs and see if there are errors in them and see what can cause

in reality Magento disables error reporting in index.php so to get better reports from users enable error logging there. If it is a php error then it is logged in php error log never the less. If after enabling the error reporting to users they still get blank pages then this means premature content output before php headers are set (blank page is present no errors reported in frontend but logged to php error log)

Comment: Thanks. We are a step further. 1) I doubt, that it is really a blank page. The page, even for successful payments is "nearly blank". It could well be, that there is code in the page. this "blank page" is a user report, so treat it with care 2) also, we certainly enabled all debugging options on our dev servers. 3) the main problem is, as described, that we are not able to successfully repeat the problem here. so we need an approach to "see what the user sees" when he is reporting it.

Comment: ask for user to take a screenshot

Comment: Problem is, that the user calls long after the checkout. He clicks "buy", gets to the blank page and wonders if everything is fine now or not. Also, the source code of the page would be more helpful, as the user sees a  ..blank page ;)

Comment: as said if blank and no source then you have premature content before header issue and it is logged to system.log and to your server error_log

Comment: Sorry, but this conclusion is wrong IMHO. her you have a completely sane blank page which doesn't put a whiff into the logs: http://www.in-due.de/blank.php

Comment: we surely have logging on and don't find anything in there, that is the problem, this is why we are asking here.

have a look here: this is a customer who doesn't get forwarded to paypal at 21:27 and who is successfully 2 minutes later: https://gist.github.com/3289471

this is the situation, st

Comment: and the same inn error_log?  any javascript error can cause this as well on the redirect page

Comment: this is the error_log.. we suspect a javascript problem as well, especially as there have been  bugs (which don't apply here) which caused malformed javascript on this very page. 

I'm no javascript specialist, so I may be wrong, but as far as I see it, this happens client side, so how can we debug this? also, this is why i asked in the original post, if there is a way to somehow mirror, or tee the output sent to the client into a file, so that we see what the client sees..

Comment: come on, stop reckoning everybody is an idiot. this is a papertrailapp excerpt for everything on the system going to this customers IP and if you look very hard, you can see, that it actually contains lines from an.. error log! http://screencast.com/t/UgdD7yLjz

Comment: cool :) i don't think you are an idiot maybe just too shy to describe what you are looking or how you are debugging this . Still does not look like a line from php error log so worth to verify if you papertail  the same file you have in phpinfo(); but js error is highly likely as well

Comment: yep, cool :) - we switched some extensions we suspected from the beginning (it took a while as the alternatives had to be customized) and did eliminate the error. so the blame is in one of two extensins  and those developers will work on it. still a mystery, but not mine for now :)